# CMD Batch command "start /wait" not working in Windows 8.1?

Tags: batch-file, wildcard, command-prompt

I'm working on a very simple bat file script that worked fine in Windows 7, but seems to be having issues in Windows 8. It relies heavily on "start /wait" to execute 1 file at a time. It seems that the "start" command works just fine. However, given the folder structure, I have referenced each item as such in a command:

```
start /wait ./folder1/app1.exe
start /wait ./folder2/app2.exe
start /wait ./folder3/app3.exe
```

While this worked just fine in W7. In Windows 8.1, this results in an error message stating: "Windows cannot find '.\folder1\app1.exe'. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again."

So... Did MS replace the .\ wildcard in Windows 8 with something else? Or change it just slightly?

Yes, I know. This isn't really programming (still studying C/CPP), but any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `./` is a no-op anyway, you can just say `start /wait folder1/app1.exe`.. Are you sure the files exist?

Comment: Quite sure. As it worked in W7 and nothing about the file structure has changed. Somehow it seems to be working now. Not sure why it wasn't before D-:.

Answer (score 0):

`./` is not a wildcard. `*` and `?` are wildcards - they match any number of any characters /one any-character.

`/` is a switch indicator. `\` is a directory separator. Dangerous to confuse the two - it confuses `cmd`.

`.\` means 'relative to the current directory`. Perhaps you should display the current directory using

```
echo %cd%
```

to make sure that `cmd`'s idea of the current directory and yours agree. Also make sure the targets exist and are not hidden files.

Comment: Yeah they aren't hidden. They're just seperated into diff directories. I think it might have something to do with my environment variables. Not sure though. It's back to doing it again. Though it worked, briefly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a cmd file on my usb drive.

In Windows 7 my application started with ...

```
START /WAIT %usbDrive%\Truecrypt\TrueCrypt.exe /volume %usbDrive%\%Container% /k %usbDrive%\Truecrypt\Truecrypt.key /cache /wipecache /quit
```

... but in Windows 8.1 it has not waited to put my password in the TrueCrypt screen.

As a workaround for both Windows versions this works for me fine now.

```
START %usbDrive%\Truecrypt\TrueCrypt.exe /volume %usbDrive%\%Container% /k %usbDrive%\Truecrypt\Truecrypt.key /cache /wipecache /quit
:CHECK
ping -n 2 localhost 1>NUL 2>NUL
TASKLIST /FI "IMAGENAME eq TrueCrypt.exe" > TrueCrypt.txt
FIND /N "TrueCrypt.exe" TrueCrypt.txt 1>NUL 2>NUL
IF %ERRORLEVEL%==0 ( GOTO CHECK ) ELSE ( DEL TrueCrypt.txt )
```

At first you start the program you want, then you need a mark to go back and check if your program is still running. The next thing is to wait about 2 seconds (for ping -n ... you can also use timeout). Then you can filter the tasklist with the exeutable name and write it in a check text file. With the find command  you can grep in the check file... Finally the last line, if the application is not in the tasklist anymore the check text file will be deleted otherwise the cmd is jumping to the check mark.

I hope it will help